# Building Nylas N1 from source on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, compiling

Ubuntu doesn't seem to have whatever N1 is looking for when compiling from source. Here's the output I get when running the initial scripts:

```
N1-master$ script/grunt
/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory
```

Has anyone successfully compiled from master and could they provide a guide?

Edit: running the scripts/bootstrap command gives the following error even following the guide linked by edwinksl:

```
$ script/bootstrap 
Node: v4.2.6
npm: v3.5.2

---> Installing N1 build tools
     This goes inside the `build` folder and runs `npm install`
     It will use the system `npm` to bootstrap our own N1 npm.
     Our build tools (like Grunt) need to be compiled against Node via `npm`.
     Everything else needs to be compiled against Chromium with `apm`.

     $ npm --userconfig="/home/jarlath/Downloads/N1-master/.npmrc" install --loglevel error --cwd="/home/jarlath/Downloads/N1-master/build" --ignoreStdout=true 

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-24-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "--userconfig=/home/jarlath/Downloads/N1-master/.npmrc" "install" "--loglevel" "error"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! path /home/jarlath/.npm/registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-less/.cache.json.4179490079
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall lstat

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/home/jarlath/.npm/registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-less/.cache.json.4179490079'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/home/jarlath/.npm/registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-less/.cache.json.4179490079'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/jarlath/Downloads/N1-master/build/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/nylas/N1/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#getting-started?

Comment: Thanks. The script/bootstrap command is failing however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you've installed nodejs (`sudo apt-get install nodejs`), the problem is the same as reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20886217/browserify-error-usr-bin-env-node-no-such-file-or-directory) — Ubuntu and Debian now install node at `/usr/bin/nodejs` rather than `/usr/bin/node`.

The two solutions least likely to break your system (in the long-run), are either:

1. Install nodejs-legacy (`sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy`), which provides a symlink from node to nodejs. ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20915436))
2. Use update-alternatives to provide the symlink ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24592328)):

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/node nodejs /usr/bin/nodejs 100
   ```

Comment: That takes things a step further, thank you. But the guide linked to by edwinksl doesn't seem to be using Ubuntu as a reference build environment. I'll update the question with the subsequent error.

Comment: After following your answer, I additionally added a PPA for the official latest node as well as npm ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/6237400/1007385).

Then
sudo apt-get install libgnome-keyring-dev
sudo npm config set python /usr/bin/python2 -g

And follow the install instructions again.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the original question